# Create pst file with custom name

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I am creating a new pst file using the below code. But the pst file is created with the default name of "Outlook Data File" in Outlook. I don't find any option to set the name of the new pst file.

```
Set objNS = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
objNS.AddStoreEx "C:\Users\pitarr\Documents\Outlook Files\f23.pst",2
```

[image: pst file name]

Comment: According to [this article](https://forums.slipstick.com/threads/16707-how-do-i-change-the-display-name-of-a-pst-store/post-55710) - *"if you only want to change the name, the user sees in Outlook for the new store, it's enough just to change the `Name` of the Defaultfolder of the store"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling the SetProperty method of the PropertyAccessor object returned by the data Store you added.  For example:

```
Const PR_DISPLAY_NAME = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3001001F"
Dim oStore, oPA
For Each oStore in objNS.Stores
    If oStore.FilePath = "C:\Users\pitarr\Documents\Outlook Files\f23.pst" Then
        Set oPA = oStore.PropertyAccessor
        oPA.SetProperty PR_DISPLAY_NAME, "SomeNewName"
    End If
Next
```

Otherwise, see if renaming the root folder of the store is sufficient, as Lankymart suggests:

```
Dim oStore, oFolder
For Each oStore in objNS.Stores
    If oStore.FilePath = "C:\Users\pitarr\Documents\Outlook Files\f23.pst" Then
        Set oFolder = oStore.GetRootFolder()
        oFolder.Name = "SomeNewName"
    End If
Next
```

BTW, both examples above are untested, and may be dependent upon the encoding used.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well done, you followed the [the article linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59835095/create-pst-file-with-custom-name#comment105809814_59835095) well, which is what I expected the OP to do.

Answer (score -1):

```
 Sub bt_newpst_Click()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
    
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set ns = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    ns.AddStore "D:\Test\" & CStr("TypeName") & ".pst"
    ilast = ns.Session.Folders.Count
    MsgBox ns.Session.Folders.Item(ilast)
    
    Set ns = Nothing
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: The question is tagged vbscript, not VBA. And why would you convert a string to to a string? `CStr("TypeName")`